# Bad rendering of ParticleSystems in Three.js with low graphic cards

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, particle-system

I am trying to use particle systems to speed up the rendering of a system of stars, but I've noticed that the display is really bad on weak graphic cards (for example on Intel HD, which are pretty widespread). The particles, which should have a specific texture, are replaced by ugly squares with strange colors and transparency. For instance, [this system of particles](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ParticleSystem-Dynamic.html) renders to :

[image]

This can be reproduced with any instance of THREE.ParticleSystem or THREE.Points (the more modern version). All the other THREE objects (Sphere, Cubes, Planes, etc.) are rendering well on my GPU, only particles bug.

Is there a way to avoid this effect? Otherwise, is there another method than particle systems to display a large number of objects without slowing down?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific case but I've found that drawing a 'Point' primitives may be problematic for some GPUs, drivers and/or API versions.
They are just a primitive type and should work the same as Triangles and Lines, but for some GPUs - especially the low-end ones - they just don't work. And if the drawing Points works by itself - it doesn't support point sizes, or texturing, or something else...

In such case you may replace them with regular textured quad and it should be fine. You'll probably lose some performance this way so you may keep both approaches and select one based on GPU.